# How can I automatically animate an already structured image gallery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a responsive design already structured only in HTML5 / CSS3 given a tutorial that I observed on YouTube but in the video it was only packaged, I miss the important thing I dedicated to search but I did not find the second part or another video that explains or is reference At the same, review each of the tutorials on the channel but without success. :/

This is the complete code, adapted to any mobile device and computers.

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

#app {
  width: 90%;
  height: 85%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.ui-big-images {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
}

.ui-big-image {
  width: 100%;
  margin-right: -100%;
}

.ui-big-image img {
  -o-object-fit: cover;
  object-fit: cover;
  -o-object-position: center 20%;
  object-position: center 20%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.ui-thumbnails {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-box-pack: start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  padding-top: .5rem;
  padding-right: 45%;
  padding-right: calc( 45% + .5rem);
}

.ui-thumbnail {
  display: block;
  margin-right: .5rem;
  padding: .5rem 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.ui-cuticle {
  background-color: #D4A12D;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: .25rem;
  width: 100%;
}

.ui-thumbnail>img {
  width: auto;
}

.ui-content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 40%;
  right: 5%;
  bottom: 0;
}

.ui-articles {
  background: #493e56;
  color: white;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: stretch;
  align-items: stretch;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.ui-article {
  padding: 1.5rem;
  width: 100%;
  margin-right: -100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.ui-paragraph {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: .7rem;
  line-height: 1.7;
}

.ui-nav {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 100%;
  background: inherit;
}

.ui-nav button {
  background: #493e56;
  border: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  padding: .5em;
  width: 2em;
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: monospace;
  -webkit-transition: inherit;
  transition: inherit;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 300ms;
  transition-duration: 300ms;
}

.ui-nav button:hover,
.ui-nav button:focus {
  background: #D4A12D;
  outline: none;
}

.ui-nav button:active {
  outline: none;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0.25em);
  transform: translateY(0.25em);
  -webkit-transition-duration: 100ms;
  transition-duration: 100ms;
}

.ui-heading {
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.ui-heading:before {
  content: 'Animator';
  font-size: .5rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}


/* ---------------------------------- */

.ui-big-image {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.ui-big-image img {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.85);
  transform: scale(0.85);
}

.ui-big-image[data-active]~.ui-big-image {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

.ui-big-image[data-active] {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
  transform: translateX(0%);
}

.ui-big-image[data-active] img {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}


/* ---------------------------------- */

.ui-article {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.ui-article:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #D4A12D;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.35s;
  transition-duration: 0.35s;
  z-index: 1;
}

.ui-article[data-active]~.ui-article {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

.ui-article[data-active] {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
  transform: translateX(0%);
}

.ui-article[data-active]:before {
  opacity: 0;
}


/* ---------------------------------- */

.ui-thumbnail>img {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.35s;
  transition-duration: 0.35s;
}

.ui-thumbnail:active>img {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
  transform: scale(0.9);
  -webkit-transition-duration: 100ms;
  transition-duration: 100ms;
}

.ui-thumbnail:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.ui-cuticle {
  display: none;
}

.ui-thumbnail[data-active]>img,
.ui-thumbnail:hover>img {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
  filter: grayscale(0%);
}

.ui-thumbnail[data-active] .ui-cuticle {
  display: block;
}


/* ---------------------------------- */

body {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #1A130C;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition-property: opacity, -webkit-transform, -webkit-filter;
  transition-property: opacity, -webkit-transform, -webkit-filter;
  transition-property: transform, opacity, filter;
  transition-property: transform, opacity, filter, -webkit-transform, -webkit-filter;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.7s, 0.7s, 0.7s;
  transition-duration: 0.7s, 0.7s, 0.7s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.5, 0, 0.5, 1);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.5, 0, 0.5, 1);
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="app" data-state="0">
  <div class="ui-big-images">
    <div class="ui-big-image" data-key="0">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/1200/?image=1005" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="ui-big-image" data-key="1">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/1200/?image=804" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="ui-big-image" data-key="2">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/1200/?image=838" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="ui-big-image" data-key="3">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/1200/?image=832" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="ui-big-image" data-key="4">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/1200/?image=836" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="ui-big-image" data-key="5">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/1200/?image=823" alt="" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ui-thumbnails">
    <div class="ui-thumbnail" tabindex="-1" data-key="0">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/1200/?image=1005" alt="" />
      <div class="ui-cuticle" data-flip-key="cuticle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-thumbnail" tabindex="-1" data-key="1">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/1200/?image=804" alt="" />
      <div class="ui-cuticle" data-flip-key="cuticle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-thumbnail" tabindex="-1" data-key="2">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/1200/?image=838" alt="" />
      <div class="ui-cuticle" data-flip-key="cuticle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-thumbnail" tabindex="-1" data-key="3">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/1200/?image=832" alt="" />
      <div class="ui-cuticle" data-flip-key="cuticle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-thumbnail" tabindex="-1" data-key="4">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/1200/?image=836" alt="" />
      <div class="ui-cuticle" data-flip-key="cuticle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-thumbnail" tabindex="-1" data-key="5">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/1200/?image=823" alt="" />
      <div class="ui-cuticle" data-flip-key="cuticle"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ui-content">

    <nav class="ui-nav">
      <button id="prev" tabindex="-1" title="Previous">&lt;</button>
      <button id="next" tabindex="-1" title="Next">&gt;</button>
    </nav>

    <div class="ui-articles">
      <article class="ui-article" data-key="0">
        <h2 class="ui-heading">Stephen Shaw</h2>
        <p class="ui-paragraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae cupiditate assumenda nemo delectus totam atque quas suscipit dicta.</p>
      </article>
      <article class="ui-article" data-key="1">
        <h2 class="ui-heading">David Khourshid</h2>
        <p class="ui-paragraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod sapiente soluta iusto molestias ullam. </p>
      </article>
      <article class="ui-article" data-key="2">
        <h2 class="ui-heading">Coding Compadre</h2>
        <p class="ui-paragraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p>
      </article>
      <article class="ui-article" data-key="3">
        <h2 class="ui-heading">Boolean Buddy</h2>
        <p class="ui-paragraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. </p>
      </article>
      <article class="ui-article" data-key="4">
        <h2 class="ui-heading">Animation Amigo</h2>
        <p class="ui-paragraph">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestias exercitationem voluptatibus</p>
      </article>
      <article class="ui-article" data-key="5">
        <h2 class="ui-heading">Keyframe Companion</h2>
        <p class="ui-paragraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae soluta reprehenderit, ut doloribus corrupti</p>
      </article>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I animate the gallery using jQuery in a simple way as shown in this image:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Can you explain to me how to do it to animate this already structured gallery.

Comment: Use `setInterval()` to advance your slides every so often. Then use `animate()` to make stuff move.  If you'd like a better answer, post whatever javascript you've come up with and someone will be happy to show you where you're going wrong.

Comment: @thingEvery I was analyzing in parts among some examples that I found on the web having the following https://jsfiddle.net/mxoe3zcv/ but it doesn't really work I don't know if I am correctly aggravating the examples that I have found friend

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve that result by using pure JavaScript or jQuery.

Reviewing the HTML markup, the `data-key` attribute is the one that indicates the current image to be displayed in the gallery, indicating the relationship between the elements with class `ui-big-image`, `ui-thumbnail` or `ui-article`.

In the case of elements with class `ui-big-image` they have a CSS declaration that makes them hidden with the following rule:

```
.ui-big-image {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
```

[image]
These elements are visible through the CSS statement:

```
.ui-big-image[data-active] {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
  transform: translateX(0%);
}
```

In the case of the elements with class `ui-article` they have a CSS declaration that makes them hidden with the following rule:

```
.ui-article {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
```

Then, through the `.ui-article[data-active]` CSS rule I invert the styles to make them visible or invisible as appropriate.

```
.ui-article[data-active] {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
    transform: translateX(0%);
}
```

The CSS declaration `ui-article:before` adds an empty section to hidden the image description. With the `.ui-article[data-active]:before` CSS rule we make it available visually.

[image]

Then, you must assign events to the thumbnails and the previous and next buttons to swap the **`data-active` attribute** in the elements of the classes mentioned above to make them visible or invisible. For thumbnails I have this function:

```
function setThumbnailAction() {
  var uiThumbnailElements = document.getElementsByClassName("ui-thumbnail");
  var i, len = uiThumbnailElements.length, thumbnail;

  itemsInGallery = len - 1;

  for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    thumbnail = uiThumbnailElements[i];
    thumbnail.onclick = function() {
      key = this.dataset.key;
      showImage();
    }
  }
}
```

In the previous code we obtain the `key` of the elements with class `ui-thumbnail`, and save it in a global `key` variable. Then we call the `showImage()` function.

The `showImage()` function is responsible for setting the `data-active` attribute with a default `true` value in it to elements with CSS class `ui-big-image`, `ui-article` and `ui-thumbnail`, using the `key` value through this selector `div.ui-big-image[data-key=\"" + key + "\"]`. At the beginning we always **remove the `data-active` attribute** with the `restoreGallery()` function.

```
function showImage() {
    restoreGallery("ui-big-image");
    restoreGallery("ui-article");
    restoreGallery("ui-thumbnail");
    var image = document.querySelector("div.ui-big-image[data-key=\"" + key + "\"]");
    image.dataset.active = "true";

    var article = document.querySelector("article.ui-article[data-key=\"" + key + "\"]");
    article.dataset.active = "true";

    var uiThumbnail = document.querySelector("div.ui-thumbnail[data-key=\"" + key + "\"]");
    uiThumbnail.dataset.active = "true";
}
```

You can see in action in these examples:

**With pure JavaScript:**

```js
(function() {

  var itemsInGallery = 0, key = 0;

  function setThumbnailAction() {
    var uiThumbnailElements = document.getElementsByClassName("ui-thumbnail"), i, len = uiThumbnailElements.length, thumbnail;
    itemsInGallery = len - 1;

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      thumbnail = uiThumbnailElements[i];
      thumbnail.onclick = function() {
        key = this.dataset.key;
        showImage();
      }
    }
  }

  function showImage() {
    restoreGallery("ui-big-image");
    restoreGallery("ui-article");
    restoreGallery("ui-thumbnail");
    var image = document.querySelector("div.ui-big-image[data-key=\"" + key + "\"]");
    image.dataset.active = "true";

    var article = document.querySelector("article.ui-article[data-key=\"" + key + "\"]");
    article.dataset.active = "true";

    var uiThumbnail = document.querySelector("div.ui-thumbnail[data-key=\"" + key + "\"]");
    uiThumbnail.dataset.active = "true";
  }

  function restoreGallery(className) {
    var items = document.getElementsByClassName(className), i, len = items.length, item;

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      item = items[i];
      item.removeAttribute("data-active");
    }
  }

  function setPrevNextAction() {
    var prev = document.getElementById("prev"), next = document.getElementById("next");

    prev.onclick = function() {
      key--;
      key = key < 0 ? 0 : key;
      showImage();
    };
    next.onclick = function() {
      key++;
      key = key > itemsInGallery ? itemsInGallery : key;
      showImage();
    };
  }

  setThumbnailAction();
  setPrevNextAction();
  showImage();

  var timeInSeconds = 5;
  setInterval(function() {
    key++;
    key = key > itemsInGallery ? 0 : key;
    showImage();
  }, timeInSeconds * 1000);
}());
```

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

#app {
  width: 90%;
  height: 85%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.ui-big-images {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
}

.ui-big-image {
  width: 100%;
  margin-right: -100%;
}

.ui-big-image img {
  -o-object-fit: cover;
  object-fit: cover;
  -o-object-position: center 20%;
  object-position: center 20%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.ui-thumbnails {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-box-pack: start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  padding-top: .5rem;
  padding-right: 45%;
  padding-right: calc( 45% + .5rem);
}

.ui-thumbnail {
  display: block;
  margin-right: .5rem;
  padding: .5rem 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.ui-cuticle {
  background-color: #D4A12D;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: .25rem;
  width: 100%;
}

.ui-thumbnail>img {
  width: auto;
}

.ui-content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 40%;
  right: 5%;
  bottom: 0;
}

.ui-articles {
  background: #493e56;
  color: white;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: stretch;
  align-items: stretch;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.ui-article {
  padding: 1.5rem;
  width: 100%;
  margin-right: -100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.ui-paragraph {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: .7rem;
  line-height: 1.7;
}

.ui-nav {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 100%;
  background: inherit;
}

.ui-nav button {
  background: #493e56;
  border: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  padding: .5em;
  width: 2em;
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: monospace;
  -webkit-transition: inherit;
  transition: inherit;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 300ms;
  transition-duration: 300ms;
}

.ui-nav button:hover,
.ui-nav button:focus {
  background: #D4A12D;
  outline: none;
}

.ui-nav button:active {
  outline: none;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0.25em);
  transform: translateY(0.25em);
  -webkit-transition-duration: 100ms;
  transition-duration: 100ms;
}

.ui-heading {
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.ui-heading:before {
  content: 'Animator';
  font-size: .5rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}


/* --- */

.ui-big-image {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.ui-big-image img {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.85);
  transform: scale(0.85);
}

.ui-big-image[data-active]~.ui-big-image {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

.ui-big-image[data-active] {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
  transform: translateX(0%);
}

.ui-big-image[data-active] img {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}


/* --- */

.ui-article {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.ui-article:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #D4A12D;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.35s;
  transition-duration: 0.35s;
  z-index: 1;
}

.ui-article[data-active]~.ui-article {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

.ui-article[data-active] {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
  transform: translateX(0%);
}

.ui-article[data-active]:before {
  opacity: 0;
}


/* --- */

.ui-thumbnail>img {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.35s;
  transition-duration: 0.35s;
}

.ui-thumbnail:active>img {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
  transform: scale(0.9);
  -webkit-transition-duration: 100ms;
  transition-duration: 100ms;
}

.ui-thumbnail:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.ui-cuticle {
  display: none;
}

.ui-thumbnail[data-active]>img,
.ui-thumbnail:hover>img {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
  filter: grayscale(0%);
}

.ui-thumbnail[data-active] .ui-cuticle {
  display: block;
}


/* --- */

body {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #1A130C;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition-property: opacity, -webkit-transform, -webkit-filter;
  transition-property: opacity, -webkit-transform, -webkit-filter;
  transition-property: transform, opacity, filter;
  transition-property: transform, opacity, filter, -webkit-transform, -webkit-filter;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.7s, 0.7s, 0.7s;
  transition-duration: 0.7s, 0.7s, 0.7s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.5, 0, 0.5, 1);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.5, 0, 0.5, 1);
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="app" data-state="0">
  <div class="ui-big-images">
    <div class="ui-big-image" data-key="0">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/1200/?image=1005" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="ui-big-image" data-key="1">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/1200/?image=804" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="ui-big-image" data-key="2">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/1200/?image=838" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="ui-big-image" data-key="3">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/1200/?image=832" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="ui-big-image" data-key="4">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/1200/?image=836" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="ui-big-image" data-key="5">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/1200/?image=823" alt="" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ui-thumbnails">
    <div class="ui-thumbnail" tabindex="-1" data-key="0">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/1200/?image=1005" alt="" />
      <div class="ui-cuticle" data-flip-key="cuticle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-thumbnail" tabindex="-1" data-key="1">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/1200/?image=804" alt="" />
      <div class="ui-cuticle" data-flip-key="cuticle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-thumbnail" tabindex="-1" data-key="2">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/1200/?image=838" alt="" />
      <div class="ui-cuticle" data-flip-key="cuticle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-thumbnail" tabindex="-1" data-key="3">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/1200/?image=832" alt="" />
      <div class="ui-cuticle" data-flip-key="cuticle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-thumbnail" tabindex="-1" data-key="4">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/1200/?image=836" alt="" />
      <div class="ui-cuticle" data-flip-key="cuticle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-thumbnail" tabindex="-1" data-key="5">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/1200/?image=823" alt="" />
      <div class="ui-cuticle" data-flip-key="cuticle"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ui-content">

    <nav class="ui-nav">
      <button id="prev" tabindex="-1" title="Previous">&lt;</button>
      <button id="next" tabindex="-1" title="Next">&gt;</button>
    </nav>

    <div class="ui-articles">
      <article class="ui-article" data-key="0">
        <h2 class="ui-heading">Stephen Shaw</h2>
        <p class="ui-paragraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae cupiditate assumenda nemo delectus totam atque quas suscipit dicta.</p>
      </article>
      <article class="ui-article" data-key="1">
        <h2 class="ui-heading">David Khourshid</h2>
        <p class="ui-paragraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod sapiente soluta iusto molestias ullam. </p>
      </article>
      <article class="ui-article" data-key="2">
        <h2 class="ui-heading">Coding Compadre</h2>
        <p class="ui-paragraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p>
      </article>
      <article class="ui-article" data-key="3">
        <h2 class="ui-heading">Boolean Buddy</h2>
        <p class="ui-paragraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. </p>
      </article>
      <article class="ui-article" data-key="4">
        <h2 class="ui-heading">Animation Amigo</h2>
        <p class="ui-paragraph">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestias exercitationem voluptatibus</p>
      </article>
      <article class="ui-article" data-key="5">
        <h2 class="ui-heading">Keyframe Companion</h2>
        <p class="ui-paragraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae soluta reprehenderit, ut doloribus corrupti</p>
      </article>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**With jQuery:**

```js
$(function() {

  var itemsInGallery = 0, key = 0;

  function setThumbnailAction() {

    var uiThumbnailElements = $(".ui-thumbnail");
    itemsInGallery = uiThumbnailElements.length - 1;

    uiThumbnailElements.on("click", function() {
      key = $(this).data("key");
      showImage();
    });
  }

  function showImage() {
    restoreGallery("ui-big-image");
    restoreGallery("ui-article");
    restoreGallery("ui-thumbnail");

    var image = $("div.ui-big-image[data-key=\"" + key + "\"]");
    image.attr("data-active", "true");

    var article = $("article.ui-article[data-key=\"" + key + "\"]");
    article.attr("data-active", "true");

    var uiThumbnail = $("div.ui-thumbnail[data-key=\"" + key + "\"]");
    uiThumbnail.attr("data-active", "true");
  }

  function restoreGallery(className) {
    $("." + className).removeAttr("data-active");
  }

  function setPrevNextAction() {
    var prev = $("#prev"), next = $("#next");

    prev.on("click", function() {
      key--;
      key = key < 0 ? 0 : key;
      showImage();
    });
    next.on("click", function() {
      key++;
      key = key > itemsInGallery ? itemsInGallery : key;
      showImage();
    });
  }

  setThumbnailAction();
  setPrevNextAction();
  showImage();

  var timeInSeconds = 5;
  setInterval(function() {
    key++;
    key = key > itemsInGallery ? 0 : key;
    showImage();
  }, timeInSeconds * 1000);
}());
```

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

#app {
  width: 90%;
  height: 85%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.ui-big-images {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
}

.ui-big-image {
  width: 100%;
  margin-right: -100%;
}

.ui-big-image img {
  -o-object-fit: cover;
  object-fit: cover;
  -o-object-position: center 20%;
  object-position: center 20%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.ui-thumbnails {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-box-pack: start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  padding-top: .5rem;
  padding-right: 45%;
  padding-right: calc( 45% + .5rem);
}

.ui-thumbnail {
  display: block;
  margin-right: .5rem;
  padding: .5rem 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.ui-cuticle {
  background-color: #D4A12D;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: .25rem;
  width: 100%;
}

.ui-thumbnail>img {
  width: auto;
}

.ui-content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 40%;
  right: 5%;
  bottom: 0;
}

.ui-articles {
  background: #493e56;
  color: white;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: stretch;
  align-items: stretch;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.ui-article {
  padding: 1.5rem;
  width: 100%;
  margin-right: -100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.ui-paragraph {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: .7rem;
  line-height: 1.7;
}

.ui-nav {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 100%;
  background: inherit;
}

.ui-nav button {
  background: #493e56;
  border: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  padding: .5em;
  width: 2em;
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: monospace;
  -webkit-transition: inherit;
  transition: inherit;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 300ms;
  transition-duration: 300ms;
}

.ui-nav button:hover,
.ui-nav button:focus {
  background: #D4A12D;
  outline: none;
}

.ui-nav button:active {
  outline: none;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0.25em);
  transform: translateY(0.25em);
  -webkit-transition-duration: 100ms;
  transition-duration: 100ms;
}

.ui-heading {
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.ui-heading:before {
  content: 'Animator';
  font-size: .5rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}


/* --- */

.ui-big-image {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.ui-big-image img {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.85);
  transform: scale(0.85);
}

.ui-big-image[data-active]~.ui-big-image {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

.ui-big-image[data-active] {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
  transform: translateX(0%);
}

.ui-big-image[data-active] img {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}


/* --- */

.ui-article {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.ui-article:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #D4A12D;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.35s;
  transition-duration: 0.35s;
  z-index: 1;
}

.ui-article[data-active]~.ui-article {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

.ui-article[data-active] {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
  transform: translateX(0%);
}

.ui-article[data-active]:before {
  opacity: 0;
}


/* --- */

.ui-thumbnail>img {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.35s;
  transition-duration: 0.35s;
}

.ui-thumbnail:active>img {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
  transform: scale(0.9);
  -webkit-transition-duration: 100ms;
  transition-duration: 100ms;
}

.ui-thumbnail:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.ui-cuticle {
  display: none;
}

.ui-thumbnail[data-active]>img,
.ui-thumbnail:hover>img {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
  filter: grayscale(0%);
}

.ui-thumbnail[data-active] .ui-cuticle {
  display: block;
}


/* --- */

body {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #1A130C;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition-property: opacity, -webkit-transform, -webkit-filter;
  transition-property: opacity, -webkit-transform, -webkit-filter;
  transition-property: transform, opacity, filter;
  transition-property: transform, opacity, filter, -webkit-transform, -webkit-filter;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.7s, 0.7s, 0.7s;
  transition-duration: 0.7s, 0.7s, 0.7s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.5, 0, 0.5, 1);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.5, 0, 0.5, 1);
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="app" data-state="0">
  <div class="ui-big-images">
    <div class="ui-big-image" data-key="0">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/1200/?image=1005" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="ui-big-image" data-key="1">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/1200/?image=804" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="ui-big-image" data-key="2">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/1200/?image=838" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="ui-big-image" data-key="3">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/1200/?image=832" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="ui-big-image" data-key="4">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/1200/?image=836" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="ui-big-image" data-key="5">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/1200/?image=823" alt="" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ui-thumbnails">
    <div class="ui-thumbnail" tabindex="-1" data-key="0">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/1200/?image=1005" alt="" />
      <div class="ui-cuticle" data-flip-key="cuticle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-thumbnail" tabindex="-1" data-key="1">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/1200/?image=804" alt="" />
      <div class="ui-cuticle" data-flip-key="cuticle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-thumbnail" tabindex="-1" data-key="2">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/1200/?image=838" alt="" />
      <div class="ui-cuticle" data-flip-key="cuticle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-thumbnail" tabindex="-1" data-key="3">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/1200/?image=832" alt="" />
      <div class="ui-cuticle" data-flip-key="cuticle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-thumbnail" tabindex="-1" data-key="4">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/1200/?image=836" alt="" />
      <div class="ui-cuticle" data-flip-key="cuticle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-thumbnail" tabindex="-1" data-key="5">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/1200/?image=823" alt="" />
      <div class="ui-cuticle" data-flip-key="cuticle"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ui-content">

    <nav class="ui-nav">
      <button id="prev" tabindex="-1" title="Previous">&lt;</button>
      <button id="next" tabindex="-1" title="Next">&gt;</button>
    </nav>

    <div class="ui-articles">
      <article class="ui-article" data-key="0">
        <h2 class="ui-heading">Stephen Shaw</h2>
        <p class="ui-paragraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae cupiditate assumenda nemo delectus totam atque quas suscipit dicta.</p>
      </article>
      <article class="ui-article" data-key="1">
        <h2 class="ui-heading">David Khourshid</h2>
        <p class="ui-paragraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod sapiente soluta iusto molestias ullam. </p>
      </article>
      <article class="ui-article" data-key="2">
        <h2 class="ui-heading">Coding Compadre</h2>
        <p class="ui-paragraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p>
      </article>
      <article class="ui-article" data-key="3">
        <h2 class="ui-heading">Boolean Buddy</h2>
        <p class="ui-paragraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. </p>
      </article>
      <article class="ui-article" data-key="4">
        <h2 class="ui-heading">Animation Amigo</h2>
        <p class="ui-paragraph">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestias exercitationem voluptatibus</p>
      </article>
      <article class="ui-article" data-key="5">
        <h2 class="ui-heading">Keyframe Companion</h2>
        <p class="ui-paragraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae soluta reprehenderit, ut doloribus corrupti</p>
      </article>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]
Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, friend to be automatic after x minutes or seconds pass the images would you help me only with that detail please, thank you.

Comment: @Valentina Yes of course. I have updated my answer with a `setInterval()` function that will execute the **`showImage()`** function every **5 seconds** by default for the examples in JavaScript and jQuery.

Comment: friend was trying to activate the color when automatic pass or when he clicked that gives the same given to this style rule: `.ui-thumbnail[data-active]>img,
.ui-thumbnail:hover>img {
 -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
 filter: grayscale(0%);
}` try adding class from here `restoreGallery ("ui-cuticle");` But it does not work

Comment: @Valentina I have updated my answer based on the CSS rule with the `[data-active]` attribute, with the respective examples in JavaScript and jQuery. In conclusion, the gallery works correctly by operating the `data-key` and `data-active` attributes.